# Multiple linq joins but different operators

Tags: c#, linq

How would I express the following in LINQ?

```
select * from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 <= t2.col2
```

Here's what I've tried, but I'm not getting the desired results. I'm trying to join
the 2 tables but since `table_1` quantity is not greater or equal than what's in `table_2` quantity for `WidgetA`
I wouldn't expect there to be any records in the results (in xList ).

```
    List<anObj> table_1 = new List<anObj>();
    table_1.Add(new anObj() { Product = "WidgetA", Quantity = 0 });
    table_1.Add(new anObj() { Product = "WidgetB", Quantity = 3 });

    List<anObj> table_2 = new List<anObj>();
    table_2.Add(new anObj() { Product = "WidgetA", Quantity = 1 });
    table_2.Add(new anObj() { Product = "WidgetB", Quantity = 1 });

    var xList =
    from t1 in table_1
    join t2 in table_2
        on t1.Product equals t2.Product
    where t1.Quantity >= t2.Quantity
    select new
    {
        t1,
        t2
    };

    if (xList.Any())
        Console.WriteLine("Found");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("None"); //I'm looking for this result.
```

Comment: Turns out it matched on WidgetB and not on WidgetA which I get now, doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from t1 in t1datatable
join t2 in t2datatable
        on t1.col1 equals t2.col1
where t1.col2 <= t2.col2
select new
{
    t1,
    t2 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to write the following:

```
var q = from t1 in table_1
        from t2 in table_2.Where(x => t1.col1 == x.col1 && t1.col2 <= x.col2)
        select new { t1, t2 };
```

(It will not create a cross join execution plan in the database even though it might look so)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from t1 in db.table_1
             from t2 in db.table_2.Where(x => t1.col1 == x.col1)
                                  .Where(x => t1.col2 <= x.col2)
             select new {t1, t2};
```